# Apex Trigger Creating Duplicate Records

Tags: apex, trigger, duplicate-value

I wrote an Apex Trigger that would create a new record on a custom object whenever the Results__c picklist is set to 3 specific values. Everything seems to functional, but it always creates 2 records that are exactly the same. Any insight as to why would be great.

```
trigger createVendorRestriction on Opportunity (after update) {
List<Vendor_Exclusion__c> vend = new List<Vendor_Exclusion__c>();

for(Opportunity v : Trigger.new)
{

    if((v.Results__c == 'Product restricted at account type' || v.Results__c == 'Not a fit for this account' || v.Results__c == 'Lack of interest to work with vendor') && count == 0)
    {
        Vendor_Exclusion__c s = new Vendor_Exclusion__c(
        Name = v.Vendor_Name__c,
        Account__c = v.AccountId,
        Start_Date__c = Date.today(),
        Vendor__c = v.Vendor__c);
        insert s;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can also check this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332407&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Are you entering two opportunities with the same vender and accountId? Have you made sure you arnt running into a recursion issue? What happens when you update just one opportunity?

Comment: Along with TSmith's answer below - if you have workflow that is updating the opp after you perform a manual update, the trigger will run again.  See [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to remove the `DML` from the for loop. This will inevitably cause you additional platform limit issues in which you can confirm by unit testing.

I am unsure what `count` is used for as I do not see it declared within the shared code, so a compilation error is coming your way.

```
trigger createVendorRestriction on Opportunity (after update) {
    List<Vendor_Exclusion__c> vend = new List<Vendor_Exclusion__c>();

    for (Opportunity v : Trigger.new) {
        if ((v.Results__c == 'Product restricted at account type' ||
                v.Results__c == 'Not a fit for this account' ||
                v.Results__c == 'Lack of interest to work with vendor')
                && count == 0) {
            Vendor_Exclusion__c s = new Vendor_Exclusion__c(
            Name = v.Vendor_Name__c,
            Account__c = v.AccountId,
            Start_Date__c = Date.today(),
            Vendor__c = v.Vendor__c);
            vend.add(s)
        }
    }
    insert vend;
}
```

If you are still running into duplicate records, I suggest you extract a log file to understand where/what else the record is being inserted. There may be other declarative functions completing what you expect to only take place in Apex.